# What /\b([a-zA-Z]+) \1\b/gi mean in Javascript RegExp

Tags: javascript, regex

I am studying regexp, there are examples. 
What's the different of g1 and g2 ?

```
var g1 = /\b([a-zA-Z]+) \b/gi.exec("Is is this is a the cost of of gas going up?");
var g2 = /\b([a-zA-Z]+) \1\b/gi.exec("Is is this is a the cost of of gas going up?");

console.log(g1);      // result is ["Is ", "Is", index: 0"]
console.log(g2);      // result is ["Is is", "Is", index: 0"]
```

Comment: use Regexr.com and it will help you

Comment: `\1` is a back reference, that's why `Is` is matched twice in the seconds example.

Comment: Please refer to: [What does this Regex Mean?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22937618/1620622) in the future for help on what a certain regex does

Comment: It means what the documentation says it means.

Comment: If you're using the `i` flag, you don't need to say `[a-zA-Z]`.

Answer (score 0):

A bunch of upper- and lowercase letters followed by space and that exact bunch second time. For example: `UserName UserName` or `jnDJkjLKSdcSJ jnDJkjLKSdcSJ`.

The difference is that `g1` doesn't match the repetition of this bunch, because there is no `\1` in it.

---

**Clarified**:

> `/\b([a-zA-Z]+) \b/gi`

```
/       start regexp
\b      match a word boundary
(…)     create a capturing group
[…]     create a class of characters to match one of them
a-z     match any character between "a" and "z" ("a", "b", "c", "d", "e" …)
A-Z     match any character between "A" and "Z" ("A", "B", "C", "D", "E" …)
+       match one or more of a preceding token (see above)
        match space sign (exactly)
\1      match first capturing group
\b      match a word boundary
/gi     finish regexp and set flags "global" and "case-insensitive"

\b([a-zA-Z]+) \b
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]
*(picture is clickable)*

Comment: It would be nice to provide information such as (1) what the `\1` is called (2) and a link to documentation.